# How to load images onto Android canvas

Tags: android

I have been trying to draw a bitmap image onto the canvas from Android and all it displays is a blank white screen. Whenever my app starts up, I am calling this in my game - view class which extends `View` and overrides the `onDraw` method:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Player {
    private int x, y;
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private FileInputStream s;
    File file;

    public Player(int x,int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void render(Canvas c) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        file = new File("C:\\Users\\Anonymous\\Desktop");
        s = new FileInputStream(file);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(s);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        c.drawBitmap(bmp,0,0,p);
        s.close();
    }

    public void tick() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Not positive, but I don't think you can access a file on the computer when running the app on an Android device, even when connected via USB.

Comment: So no one knows the answer

Comment: Try adding the image to your Android device, or add it to your project, then load it from there.